# Добавление картинок. attr, jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, массивы

Всем привет. Никак не поддается.

В `arr` приходит массив из 20 объектов. Нужно добавить 20 картинок с 20 уникальными `src`. Но получается, что ко всем добавляется последняя ссылка. Я так понимаю, теряется контекст? Как исправить?

```
function addPics(arr) {

arr.then(data => {
    $(".divPic").append("<img>");
    $("img").attr("src", data[0].url);
});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это

```
$("img").attr("src", data[0].url);
```

устанавливает атрибут `src` всем сразу картинкам на странице.

Замените Ваши две строчки на:

```
$("<img />").attr("src", data[0].url).appendTo(".divPic");
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @lex Пожалуйста. Успехов!